# Call set-returning plpgsql function for each row returned from a query

Tags: arrays, postgresql, plpgsql, set-returning-functions, sql-domain

In my Postgres 9.6 database I have the following custom domain and table definition:

```
create domain lowResData as
    float[21];

create table myRawValues (
    id text,
    myData lowResData,
    xAxis lowResData,
    primary key(id)    
);
```

The following functions are able to produce the result I want for a single item.

```
create function getData(_id 'text') returns float[] as $$
select myData
from myRawValues
where id = _id
$$ language sql;

create function getAxis(_id 'text') returns float[] as $$
select xAxis 
from myRawValues
where id = _id
$$ language sql;

create function myPlotter(myarray float[], myData float[]) 
returns table (frequency float, amplitude float) as 
$$
select * 
from unnest(myarray, myData) as u;
$$ language sql;

select * from myPlotter(getAxis('123'), getData('123'));
```

[image: result1]

I want to do the same for *all* `id`'s produced from executing a particular query and end up with a result like this:

[image: reslt2]

```
create or replace function allIdLowResData() returns setof float[] as
$body$
declare r text;
begin 
    for r in (select id from myRawValues where /*SOME CONDITION*/)
    loop
    return next myPlotter(getAxis(r), getData(r));
    end loop;
    return;
end
$body$
language plpgsql;
```

Comment: For future reference, please post data as *text* not as image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `LATERAL` join to combine your set-returning function with the rest of the query. Like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION allIdLowResData()
  RETURNS TABLE (frequency float, amplitude float, id text) AS
$func$
SELECT p.*, r.id
FROM   myRawValues r
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL myPlotter(r.xAxis, r.myData) p ON true
WHERE  /*SOME CONDITION*/
$func$  LANGUAGE sql;
```

See:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

Plus, the declared return type of the function (`RETURNS`) must match what's actually returned.

Using a simpler SQL function here. You can do the same with PL/pgSQL, lead with `RETURNS QUERY` in this case.

You might be interested in these details about Postgres array definitions, [quoted from the manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html#ARRAYS-DECLARATION)

> However, the current implementation ignores any supplied array size
>   limits, i.e., the behavior is the same as for arrays of unspecified
>   length.
>
> The current implementation does not enforce the declared number of
>   dimensions either. Arrays of a particular element type are all
>   considered to be of the same type, regardless of size or number of
>   dimensions. So, declaring the array size or number of dimensions in
>   `CREATE TABLE` is simply documentation; it does not affect run-time behavior.

Meaning, your `domain` is currently noise without any effect (aside from complications). To actually enforce 1-dimensional arrays with exactly 21 elements in your table, use a `CHECK` constraint. Like:

```
CREATE DOMAIN lowResData AS float[21]  -- "[21]" is just for documentation
CONSTRAINT dim1_elem21 CHECK (array_ndims(VALUE) = 1 AND array_length(VALUE, 1) = 21);
```

I would also ditch the functions `getData()` and `getAxis()` unless there is more to them.